# Only rotate last clicked MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a project where a MovieClip gets copied when clicked and dragged. It is also possible to  rotate and scale the MovieClip with arrow keys.

But this only rotates last MovieClip dragged, not last MovieClip clicked. So if I drag a new copy, the previous dragged copies are not able to rotate or scale.

How can I change this to only make the last MovieClip clicked able to rotate and scale, when arrow keys are pressed?

Here is some of the code used (taken and slightly modified from another post):

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObject);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHit);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, noKeyHit);


function keyHit(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = true;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = true;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = true;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = true;
}


function noKeyHit(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = false;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = false;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = false;
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = false;
}


function moveObject(e:Event):void{
if(leftArrow) latestClone.rotation -=0.75;
if(rightArrow) latestClone.rotation +=0.75;
if(upArrow) latestClone.scaleY +=0.01
if(downArrow) latestClone.scaleY -=0.01;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are scaling and rotating `latestClone`.
Somewhere outside of this code you are setting the value of `latestClone`.
If you want to rotate the latest clicked MovieClip, add an event listener to the click:

```
latestClone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCloneClick);
function onCloneClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    latestClone = target;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. However I found it worked best if I replaced CLICK with MOUSE_DOWN, but thank you very much for helping me find the answer.